How to integrate Azure function in apim policy
I have developed an Azure function and want to integrate it in apim policy using send-request or set-backend-service policy. Can someone please help me achieve this?
I tried the below but I am not getting any result.
<set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" base-url="fun.azurewebsites.net/api/httpexample" />
<set-query-parameter name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
    <value>application/json</value>
</set-query-parameter>
<set-query-parameter name="x-functions-key" exists-action="override">
    <value>xyz</value>
</set-query-parameter>


You can directly import the function app in apim

no my requirement is to achieve it via apim policy only

I have added the correct policy to import it in my answer, please check

You don't need to integrate it using policy instead you can import it directly using Azure resource tile.





In this way, you can integrate function app with APIM and can test it using test console.

If you still want to integrate using policy then you can do so by using below given policy
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://****.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1" />
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-header name="x-functions-key" exists-action="override">
            <value>lx2****BlEPQ==</value>
        </set-header>
    </inbound>
</policies>

If you get any error while executing this policy, then you can check the detailed error message in Trace.

using set-backend-service gives empty response. are you getting any response? in my function i am returning "welcome" text but i couldnt see that response in apim

Yes I am getting response. Can you check in trace, if possible share the trace message. Use the same policy which I have shared


i am executing it from postman. 2. x-functions-key ---> which key have you passed to this param


Can you try in apim test console?

it is restricted, i can use only postman. 2. x-functions-key ---> which key have you passed to this param

I am using this key

I believe this key will generate in function app when you integrate directly

is there any other configuration should be done for accessing the function app?

Yes, you can do it by using API management blade available in function app.

deployed function throws "timeout error". tried updating the timeout value in host.json but no luck.

Which function app plan you are using? Consider using App service plan as it comes with Always on option

timeout issue resolved by doing JDK configuration changes.
